# Run javascript function after login if checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, checkbox

I am making a Wordpress site where users can vote on posts if the are loggedin, this is currently working. What I want to do now, is to give them the option to place their votes by selecting a checkbox before they have loggedin on the site. If the checkbox is not selected the function must run as it does now. I hope I was clear in my explanation. Thank you in advance.

This is the form that runs the script below if the users are loggedin. **And have not already voted by selecting the checkbox in the form at the bottom, before loggin in.**

```
 <textarea id="msg" maxlength="100" rows="4" class="widget_textarea"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="vote widget_button">Sign</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="<?php the_ID() ?>">
```

The script than users can run with the form above if they are loggedin. **Should also run if users selected the checkbox in the from below, before logging in.**

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
    $(".vote").html('busy');
    $url = "/vote/?petitie_id=" + $("#post_id").val() + "&msg=" + $("#msg").val();

    $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: $url
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $(".vote").html('done');
            if (data.success) {

                $(".vote").html('voted')

            } else {
                $(".vote").html('already voted');

            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('fail');
        })
});
```

The login form with **checkbox**, **this has to run the script above after login  if the checkbox was selected**.

```
<form name="loginform" class="wpuf-login-form row" id="loginform" action="/login/" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 login_section_login_forms">
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="log" class="form-control top-buffer" placeholder="Naam" value="" size="20" />
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" name="pwd"  class="form-control top-buffer" placeholder="Wachtwoord" value="" size="20" />
           </div>
           <input id="vote_for_me" type="checkbox"> Login and vote<br>
           <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 login_button">
           <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" type="button" id="myButton1" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Log In'); ?>" />
           <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo WPUF_Login::get_posted_value('redirect_to'); ?>" />
           <input type="hidden" name="wpuf_login" value="true" />
           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
           <?php wp_nonce_field('wpuf_login_action'); ?>
        </div>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cookie in JavaScript with the value of the checkbox, something like this:

```
document.cookie="vote_post123=1";
```

You could either do this using the `onclick()` event, or the form's `onsubmit()` event.

Then, upon login, redirect users to a page that checks `$_COOKIE['vote_post123']` to see if it equals 1, and perform the appropriate action or echo the appropriate JavaScript code based on that.